# AsyncStorage, store value to skip login form

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a basic login form where a user can set various credentials. I would like to store them using AsyncStorage, and skip the login screen when the user next logs in.

I use `setItem`, when  a value is changed:

```
onStudentChange(e) {
    if (e !== "") {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("loggedIn", e);
        this.props.dispatch(setStudent(e));
    }
}
```

I check its been set previously, if so update the state and navigate to a different page.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn", value => {
                 this.props.dispatch(setStudent(value));
                 this.props.navigation.navigate("Month");
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE: I can set my value, but my `.getItem` promise doesn't execute any of my console logs?**

Any ideas how I can get my value?

```
  AsyncStorage.getItem("loggedIn")
            .then(value => {
                console.log(value);
                this.props.dispatch(setStudent(value));
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Month");
            });
```

Comment: Async storage as the name suggests is async in nature, so make sure you call dispatch inside the callback/promise after you set the item.

Comment: You should put a try catch around every asyncstorage call. There's probably an issue with e who cann't be an object but a string

Comment: I can set my value but now I cant use `getItem`, any ideas?